# Pandas' read_csv with dtype=pd.CategoricalDtype() creates 'object' categories even when the input data are numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use pandas' *read_csv* with the *dtype* parameter set to *CategoricalDtype*. It does generate the *DataFrame* with categories as expected but I have noticed that the categories themselves are *object* type instead of some kind of *int*. For example,

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = 'data\n1\n2\n3\n'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), dtype=pd.CategoricalDtype())
df['data']
```

results in

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: data, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): ['1', '2', '3']
```

This is a bit surprising because if I create a list of numbers and then generate a *Series*, without using *read_csv*, the categories are *int64*.

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
pd.Series(lst, dtype=pd.CategoricalDtype())
```

results in

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: category
Categories (3, int64): [1, 2, 3]
```

I know I can pass the categories explicitly to the *CategoricalDtype* to circumvent this, but this is a bit annoying. Is this behaviour expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this behavior is expected. When reading a `csv` all data is stored as a string and `pandas` essentially guesses (intelligently) at whether or not a column is supposed to be something else after parsing the data (unless given a dtype beforehand). This is probably an oversimplification of how pandas interprets text-based files, so some one please correct me if I'm wrong or has more information to include.

If you remove the manual `dtype` in your `pd.read_csv`, pandas will read in your data and then accurately guess that the column should be of an `int` dtype. By manually setting `dtype=pd.CategoricalDtype` (note you can also achieve the result with `dtype="category"`) pandas skips the implicit conversion to an `int` dtype before converting it to a `CategoricalDtype` which is why your categories have an object dtype.

In your second example, the data in your list `lst` are all numeric. Since you aren't explicitly supplying the categories, `pandas` draws on the unique values in `lst` to create its categories. Since all the value in the categories are int, it the unique values in `lst` will be of dtype `int`. If you want your categories in your second example to be a string you'll need to recast `lst` to contain strings (e.g. `lst = [str(x) for x in lst]`), or better yet, you can replace the underlying categories with a copy that has an object/string dtype after creation of the `Series`.

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
s = pd.Series(lst, dtype=pd.CategoricalDtype())

# replace underlying categories with an string version
s = s.cat.rename_categories(s.cat.categories.astype(str))

print(s)
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): ['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: Thanks. I see what you mean. I just find that behaviour a little frustrating because if I want to query the dataframe, I have to put the numbers inside quotes. It actually deceived me for a while before I realized that. It would probably be a better idea to cast the column to an *int* type, but when I'm dealing with a big dataset, it becomes tedious to verify the optimal type to optimize memory usage.

Comment: Yeah, if you're dealing with numeric data already there's really no benefit to use `pd.CategoricalDtype`. It is mainly beneficial for columns that contain strings with a lot of repeated values.